# How to send data from button click to php in the same file without using ajax

Tags: php, html

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello Wolrd!";

if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 echo "hello";
}

else {
}
?>
<h2> Sending data onclick </h2>
 <button name = "submit" id="submit" onclick="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" > order </button>
 

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code how I am trying to work. On clicking the button the php script should be executed but nothing is happening.

Comment: what are you actually asking?

Comment: I just wan t to run the php script on the same file when I click a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a form with `action` blank or same page name and use `GET` or `POST` or `REQUEST` in form method. This will help you to send the data on the same page and you can use some PHP code to display the data in whatever format you want.

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    echo "Hello World!"; // will print when we run the program
        if(isset($_GET['submit']))
        {
          echo "Hello World"; // will print this after form submission.
        }
    ?>
    <h2> Sending data onclick </h2>
    <form action="" method="GET">
       <input type="submit" value="Order" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Than you very much sir

Comment: @Hem Please feel free to accept it as an answer ;)

Comment: I did as you said but still it is not printing the echo "Hello World!" statement

Comment: Try now. I have updated my answer.

Comment: do you want to print Hello world after form submit? If yes, then change `echo "Hello";` to `echo "Hello world";"`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir it is printing now. I changed the file name extension from html to php

Comment: haha, that's crazy! Glad it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="inputField">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "$_POST[inputField]";
}

else {
    // Code here
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got it we have to use form to call php

Comment: no problem, could you mark my answer?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language and the button on click event is on the client side. In your code the php code given inside the on click gets executed at the server side when the user requests the page and the output will be placed there.

The best way for doing what you need. Like submitting data to the same PHP page when the user clicks the button is to create a  in html.

```html
   <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
          echo "Data";
        }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SomeValue" >
    </form>
```

Or the other way is use PHP Session variables

```html
<?php
// BEST WAY TO PASS DATA BETWEEN PHP PAGES
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['YOUR_SESSION']))
 {
    echo "Session Data";
 }
 
 ?>
```